# Can we use multiple ObjectDB property files?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

Can we use multiple ObjectDB property files in pace automation framework ?

Answer (score 0):

**YES**, This is new feature available in PAF 4.4.0 where we can define and use multiple object DBproperty files.
**Example**: (ObjectDB File configuration at flow level)

```
<flow id="flow1" objectDBName="objectDBFile1"></flow>
```

**Example**: (ObjectDB File configuration at activity level)

```
<flow id="flow1">
<call activity="activity1" xml="activity_xml_path"
objectDBName="objectDBFile1"></call>
<call activity="activity2" xml="activity_xml_path"
objectDBName="objectDBFile2"></call>
</flow>
```